# Rails: Paypal endpoint /v2/checkout/orders returns http 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

This paypal checkout code works perfectly on localhost sandbox but fails on Heroku with a 401. When a user clicks the Paypal button a popup signin window shows up and the backend controller **/orders/create_order** is hit.

**Frontend JS**

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<%=@client_id%>"></script>
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
  env: '<%= @env %>', // Valid values are sandbox and live.
  createOrder: async () => {
      const config = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({key: '<%= @order.key %>'})
      }
      const response = await fetch('/orders/create_order', config);
      const responseData = await response.json();
      return responseData.token;
  },
  onApprove: async (data) => {
    const response = await fetch('/orders/capture_order', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({token: data.orderID})
    });
    const responseData = await response.json();
    if (responseData.status === 'COMPLETED') {
      alert('Payment success!');
      location.reload();
    }
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

**Backend Rails Controller**

```
  before_action :paypal_init

  def paypal_init
    @env = ENV["PAYPAL_ENV"]
    @client_id = ENV["PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID"]
    client_secret = ENV["PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET"]
    environment = PayPal::SandboxEnvironment.new @client_id, client_secret
    @client = PayPal::PayPalHttpClient.new environment
  end

  def create_order
    ky = params[:key]
    order = Order.where(key:ky).first

    request = PayPalCheckoutSdk::Orders::OrdersCreateRequest::new
    encoded   = Base64.strict_encode64("#{ENV["PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID"]}:#{ENV["PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET"]}")
    request.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic #{encoded}"
    request.request_body({
      :intent => 'CAPTURE',
      :purchase_units => [
        {
          :amount => {
            :currency_code => 'USD',
            :value => order.price.to_s
          }
        }
      ]
    })

    begin
      response = @client.execute(request)
      result = response.result
      order.token = result.id
      if order.save!
        return render :json => {:token => order.token}, :status => :ok
      end
    rescue PayPalHttp::HttpError => ioe
      puts ioe.status_code
      puts ioe.headers["debug_id"]
    end
  end
```

doing a `puts` on the request object gives this

> {"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Basic somevalue"},"body":{"intent":"CAPTURE","purchase_units":[{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"10"}}]},"verb":"POST","path":"/v2/checkout/orders?"}

**What I've tried**

1. I've counter checked the PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID and PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET environment variables and they are using the correct production values
2. I've tried changing PAYPAL_ENV to ***live*** and ***production*** on Heroku
3. Restarted the Heroku app countless times
4. Tried adding this line out of desperation

> request.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic #{encoded}"

5. Chewed all my finger nails

It just won't stop giving back a 401 but works perfectly on localhost with Sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my code by checking the env variable for 'sandbox' or 'live' and then initializing the `LiveEnvironment` class when we are not in sandbox

```
  def paypal_init
    @env = ENV["PAYPAL_ENV"]
    @client_id = ENV["PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID"]
    client_secret = ENV["PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET"]
    if @env == 'sandbox'
      environment = PayPal::SandboxEnvironment.new @client_id, client_secret
    else
      environment = PayPal::LiveEnvironment.new @client_id, client_secret
    end
    @client = PayPal::PayPalHttpClient.new environment
  end
```

And removed the Authorization header stuff in `create_order` method

```
encoded = Base64.strict_encode64("#{ENV["PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID"]}:#{ENV["PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET"]}")
request.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic #{encoded}"
```

It now works

Answer (score 0):

> environment = PayPal::SandboxEnvironment.new @client_id, client_secret

This is a problem if you're attempting to do things in live with a production client/secret.

Make the API behavior depend on your configured PAYPAL_ENV, rather than ignoring it.